# Functional malfunction occurs when using Swiper breakpoints in React

Tags: reactjs, resize, breakpoints, swiper.js

I'm using version 6.1.2 with react applied to Swiper in nextjs ssr environment.

```
  <Swiper
    slidesPerView={1}
    loop
    navigation
    pagination={{
      type: "bullets",
      renderBullet: (index, className) => {
        return `<div class="${className}">${index}</div>`;
      },
      clickable: true,
    }}
    breakpoints={{
      769: {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        slidesPerGroup: 3,
        pagination: { type: "fraction", clickable: true },
      },
    }}
>
```

When **width is over 769**
[pagination tpye: fraction], 
When it is less than **768**
I applied [tpye: bullets]

When changing options due to breakpoints
Cannot slide by touch 
**768<width** when switching
When sliding, 
the fraction page number is fixed and looping is possible only with the prev button. 
There is nothing similar on Stack Overflow.
**I tried with React, but the same problem occurred.**

I looked at the official document but couldn't solve it.
https://swiperjs.com/react/

Comment: it's a bug as far as i recall, i think i had similar problem. Search through issues on their github page, there could be a solution

Comment: @Aleks I've already looked at github and stakflow, but there was no similar case.

Comment: Any progress? I'm having the same problem. Couldn't find any solution.